# How do i format an HTTP request

Tags: python, sockets, http

This works just fine.

```
sock.send("GET / HTTP/1.0%s" % (CRLF))
```

When I use this one google replies by telling me the client sent a malformed request.

```
 sock.send("GET {0} HTTP/ {1}".format(path, CRLF))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the HTTP version in the second:

```
"GET {0} HTTP/ {1}"
```

should be

```
"GET {0} HTTP/1.0 {1}"
```

You also may need to remove the trailing space.